# RowIndex returning null when trying to find

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to find the rowIndex of the row that had the delete button that was clicked. However when the delete button is clicked it doesn't find the ID instead it returns null and errors out.

I have tried this:

```
$("#delete").on("click", function (e) {


        var row = $(this).closest("tr");
        row.remove();

        return false;
    });
```

but this solution doesn't post. Then I have also tried this:

```
<td><input type="submit" formaction="/LansingMileage/DeleteEntry/@item.RowIndex" value="Delete" name="Deletebtn" id="delete" /></td>
```

which is causing my null issue.

My Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
       public ActionResult DeleteEntry(string rowIndex)
        {
           // try
            {
                //rowIndex = Request.Form["Deletebtn"];
                using (db)
                {
                    LansingMileage lansing = db.LansingMileages.Find(rowIndex);
                    db.LansingMileages.Remove(lansing);
                    db.SaveChanges();

                    LansingMileageViewModel model = new LansingMileageViewModel();
                    model.Records = db.LansingMileages.OrderBy(
                        //will need to change to a select all
                        //I'm not following the Take command
                        m => m.RowIndex).ToList();
                    model.SelectedLansingMileage = null;
                    model.DisplayMode = "";

                    return View("Index", model);
                }

            }
           // catch(Exception e)
            {
                ///Debug.WriteLine(e);
            }

        }
```

My Index.cshtml:

```
<table id="LansingData" class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Action</th>
                <th>Row ID</th>
                <th>Expense Month/Yr</th>
                <th>Travel Date</th>
                <th>Travel Type</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var item in Model.Records)
            {
                if(Model.SelectedLansingMileage != null)
                {
                    if(item.RowIndex == Model.SelectedLansingMileage.RowIndex)
                    {
                        @:<tr class="SelectedLansingMileage">
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        @:<tr>
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    @:<tr>
                }
                <td><input type="submit" formaction="/LansingMileage/DeleteEntry/@item.RowIndex" value="Delete" name="Deletebtn" id="delete" /></td>
                <td>@item.RowIndex</td>
                <td>@item.ExpMonthYr</td>
                <td>@item.TravelDate</td>
                <td>@item.TripType</td>


                @:</tr>

                @*<tr id="@item.RowIndex">

                      <td><a class="Delete" href="javascript:;">Delete</a></td>
                      <td>@item.ExpMonthYr</td>
                      <td>@item.TravelDate</td>
                      <td>@item.TripType</td>
                      <!--Here is where I will create a table to display my data from the above section-->
                </tr>*@
             }
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

The desired result is that when the user clicks on the delete button it removes the row and post to the database.

Comment: Note that IDs must be unique to the document. You shouldn't be using them in for loop like that unless you append something to make it unique (like `RowIndex`).

Comment: I had the ID in there for another test I was running just forgot to remove it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Select` overload, something like:

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Select((item,index)=>new{item,index})
{   
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="submit" formaction="/LansingMileage/DeleteEntry/@item.index" value="Delete" name="Deletebtn" id="delete" />
      </td>
    </tr>
}
```

Or do it manually like this:

```
@{int RowNo = 0;}
@foreach (var item in Model) {
<tr>
    <td><input type="submit" formaction="/LansingMileage/DeleteEntry/@RowNo" value="Delete" name="Deletebtn" id="delete" /></td>
</tr>
```

Note: Why not use the @id for the row? If it's possible that rows are added while one is being deleted, bad things can happen.

Comment: The foreach you did is that supposed to be a nested foreach? Also I don't follow on how your second example is supposed to get the ID number as I just tested it and still receive null.

Comment: The @id I mentioned in the "note"? It's nothing to do with the example I gave but it was a general advice.